# Neo4j: Inserting 7k nodes is slow (Spring Data Neo4j / SpringRestGraphDatabase)

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm building an application where my users can manage dictionaries. One feature is uploading a file to initialize or update the dictionary's content.

The part of the structure I'm focusing on for a start is `Dictionary -[:CONTAINS]->Word`.
Starting from an empty database (Neo4j 1.9.4, but also tried 2.0.0M5), accessed via Spring Data Neo4j 2.3.1 in a distributed environment (therefore using SpringRestGraphDatabase, but testing with localhost), I'm trying to load 7k words in 1 dictionary. However I can't get it done in less than 8/9 minutes on a linux with core i7, 8Gb RAM and SSD drive (ulimit raised to 40000).

I've read lots of posts about loading/inserting performance using REST and I've tried to apply the advices I found but without better luck. The BatchInserter tool doesn't seem to be a good option to me due to my application constraints.

Can I hope to load 10k nodes in a matter of seconds rather than minutes ?

Here is the code I came up with, after all my readings :

```java
Map<String, Object> dicProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
dicProps.put("locale", locale);
dicProps.put("category", category);
Dictionary dictionary = template.createNodeAs(Dictionary.class, dicProps);
Map<String, Object> wordProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Set<Word> words = readFile(filename); 
for (Word gw : words) {
  wordProps.put("txt", gw.getTxt());
  Word w = template.createNodeAs(Word.class, wordProps);
  template.createRelationshipBetween(dictionary, w, Contains.class, "CONTAINS", true);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you create all your entities detached and save them all together at the end? Have a `Set<Word>` in your dictionary class appropriately annotated, create dictionary and words like regular objects with `new` and not with the template, add all words to the dict set `dict.addWord(word)`, and only at the end you persist it all with `template.save(dict)`. Any difference?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve such problem by just creating some CSV file and after that read it from Neo4j. It is needed to make such steps:

1. Write some class which get input data and base on it create CSV file (it can be one file per node kind or even you can create file which will be used to build relation).
2. In my case I have also create servlet which allow Neo4j to read that file by HTTP.
3. Create proper Cypher statements which allow to read and parse that CSV file. There are some samples of which I use (if you use Spring Data also remember about labels):

   - simple one:

     ```
     load csv with headers from {fileUrl} as line 
        merge (:UserProfile:_UserProfile {email: line.email})
     ```
   - more complicated:

     ```
     load csv with headers from {fileUrl} as line 
          match (c:Calendar {calendarId: line.calendarId})
          merge (a:Activity:_Activity {eventId: line.eventId})
     on create set  a.eventSummary = line.eventSummary,
          a.eventDescription = line.eventDescription,
          a.eventStartDateTime = toInt(line.eventStartDateTime),
          a.eventEndDateTime = toInt(line.eventEndDateTime),
          a.eventCreated = toInt(line.eventCreated), 
          a.recurringId = line.recurringId
     merge (a)-[r:EXPORTED_FROM]->c
     return count(r)
     ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

1. Usw native Neo4j API rather than spring-data-neo4j while performing batch operations.
2. Commit in batches i.e. may be for each 500 words

NOTE: There are certain properties (**type**) added by SDN which will be missing when using the native approach.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that (if by native Neo4j API you mean calling the Rest API directly).

Comment: @AlainB. Neo4j provides Java API (different than the REST API) that you can use to talk to the EMBEDDED Neo4j DB. This is more performant when using embedded Neo4j

Comment: I tried embedded mode already, with very good performance, unfortunately as mentionned in my question I can't use the embedded mode because I have several applications servers which need to talk to the Neo4j server.