# Neo4j sequential db transactions issue

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a Spring Data Neo4j application that needs to do bulk data write/read to Neo4j Community Edition (3.2).

My system configuration (Macbook pro)
16GB RAM, 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7.

Total nodes : ***120,000***. (***5*** properties in each node.)

I have ***500*** relationships per node.

Above nodes/relationships is part of initial data I need for other parts of application to work.

I use Spring Data Neo4j for read/write transactions. Each node builds its corresponding 500 relationships sequentially. So obviously it takes a significant amount of time to build all above nodes and relationships.

Sample Code:

Entity:

```
//Neo4j entity class
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

@NodeEntity
public class SamplePojo {

@GraphId
    public Long id;
    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    private Integer property3;
    private Double property4;
    private Integer property5;

@Relationship(type="has_sample_relationship",direction="OUTGOING")
    List<SamplePojo> sampleList = new ArrayList<>();

//Getters and setters...

}
```

Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;

@Repository
public interface SamplePojoRepository extends GraphRepository<SamplePojo> {

//save

}
```

Service class:

```
  @Service
    public class DataInsertion{

    @Autowired
    SamplePojoRepository repository;


    public writeToNeo4j(List<SamplePojo> pojoList){

    for(SamplePojo p : pojoList){

    // Loop through more than 100,000 objects that have properties set and relationships as well

    repository.save();    // save to neo4j db

    }  
}
     }
```

**My Observation:**

Initially, 
first few minutes , it took ***1200 write operations/minute***.

After few minutes , write operations came down significantly from ***1200*** to ***100 write operations/minute*** .

Later, it came down to ***10 write operations/minute***.

Does anyone know root cause of the problem of why Neo4j write operations slow down by time ?

Please let me know if additional information is needed, will update the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589687/neo4j-inserting-7k-nodes-is-slow-spring-data-neo4j-springrestgraphdatabase?rq=1  but none of the answers explain exactly why it happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very broad question, you should at least profile your application to identify what part slows down - is it Neo4j itself? Particular query? Spring Data Neo4j? Your application? Then it will be easier to help you.

The usual suspects are:

- your transaction is too large - split load into smaller transactions of 1k to 50k elements (nodes + relationships + properties) - this is needed because Neo4j holds transaction state in memory and it might spent to much time in GC (or even run out of memory) when you have large transactions.
- growing OGM session - again causing to much time spent in GC - clear the Session from time to time (this should be done automatically with SDN when `@Transactional` method is finished)
- there is some operation without an index that becomes slow with growing amount of data (e.g. doing full node label scan instead of using index)
- low memory for Neo4j or your application - time is spent mostly in GC
- there might be a performance issue with SDN/OGM - a reproducible test case would be great for this.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Updated my question.

Comment: @TanmayDelhikar I don't see any `@Transactional` annotation, so my guess is the transaction is too large - split the list and save it by 1k size batches